# How create materialized view refresh fast using where day>to_date(20200531)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

full code :

```
create materialized view log on TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS 
WITH ROWID,
SEQUENCE(AD_ID,day)including new values;

create materialized view log on TABLEAU.GW_CLIENTS
WITH ROWID,
SEQUENCE(id,NAME)including new values;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_CREATIVE_DCO_ADWORDS_2
NOLOGGING
NOCOMPRESS 
CACHE 
NOPARALLEL 
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND 
as
   select TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.ROWID, 
          ACC.ROWID, 
          ACC.NAME,
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.AD_ID,
          min(TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY),
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY
     FROM TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS, 
          TABLEAU.GW_CLIENTS ACC
    WHERE TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.CLIENTID=ACC.ID(+) and  TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY>TO_DATE('20200531','yyyymmdd')
 group by TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.ROWID, 
          ACC.ROWID, 
          ACC.NAME,
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.AD_ID,
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY;
```

working create materialized view

```
WHERE TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.CLIENTID=ACC.ID(+)
```

not working create materialized view

```
WHERE TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.CLIENTID=ACC.ID(+) 
    AND TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY>TO_DATE('20200531','yyyymmdd')
```

12052. 00000 -  "cannot fast refresh materialized view %s.%s"
       *Cause:    Either ROWIDs of certain tables were missing in the definition or
       the inner table of an outer join did not have UNIQUE constraints on
       join columns.
       *Action:   Specify the FORCE or COMPLETE option. If this error is got
       during creation, the materialized view definition may have be
       changed. Refer to the documentation on materialized views.

***Why cant i add a filter by date ? How to get around this limitation ?***

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Answer (score 1):

> Cause: Either ROWIDs of certain tables were missing in the definition...

For starters, you need to include the `ROWID` from each table in your select:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_CREATIVE_DCO_ADWORDS 
NOLOGGING
NOCOMPRESS 
CACHE 
NOPARALLEL 
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND 
as
   select TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.ROWID, 
          ACC.ROWID, 
          ACC.NAME,
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.AD_ID,
          min(TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY),
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY
     FROM TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS, 
          TABLEAU.GW_CLIENTS ACC
    WHERE TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.CLIENTID=ACC.ID(+)
      AND TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY>TO_DATE('20200531','yyyymmdd')
 group by TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.ROWID, 
          ACC.ROWID, 
          ACC.NAME,
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.AD_ID,
          TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY;
```

> or the inner table of an outer join did not have UNIQUE constraints on
> join columns.

Also, `TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.CLIENTID` needs to have a unique constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My query works without using rowid as well. I need working code using date filter as I wrote above. TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.CLIENTID  have a unique constraint.

Comment: The error you posted doesn't appear to relate to your date filter at all. It only pertains to the ROWID and join columns.

Comment: I changed the body of the question. The same error is returned.

Comment: Did you confirm the unique constraint(s) on your join columns? Could you post the DDL for the tables and their constraints?

Comment: Yes. PK_GW_CLIENTS Primary_Key

Comment: and that is on the `CLIENTID` column?

Comment: CLIENTID Foreign_Key

Comment: `CLIENTID` is in your join. The error message indicates that the join column on the inner table must have its own unique constraint to meet the conditions for fast refresh.

Comment: do you mean:alter table TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS add constraint u_CLIENTID unique (CLIENTID) ?

Comment: yes. the "parent" column in the join needs to be unique. it feels like you're joining from the child to the parent in this case (hard to say without seeing all of the DDL); perhaps your entire query needs to be refactored? ANSI standard join syntax would also make it easier to read.

Comment: while the table is locked. I can not add a constraint. im show pick DDL body question.

Comment: im show pick DDL body question. fats refresh quick update
using connection only supports ansi 89, left join must not. full ddl will not answer questions, everything is very simple there 2 b-tree index.

Comment: @pmdba ANSI join syntax it not possible with `FAST` refresh. It's an Oracle bug. Long time ago I created a case for it, they consider it only as "lack of documentation".

Comment: oy. sounds about right. @максимильин if you can't add (for whatever reason) that unique constraint then you'll have to refactor the query not to use that join, or to use a join whose inner table column _is_ unique (like possibly reversing the join you have). that's what the error message is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use alias:

```
select 
      TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.ROWID as GW_STATISTICS_ROWID, 
      ACC.ROWID AS ACC_ROWID, 
      ACC.NAME,
      TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.AD_ID,
      min(TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY) AS MIN_DAY,
      TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS.DAY
```

or try

```
 FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLEAU.GW_STATISTICS WHERE DAY > DATE '2020-05-31') STATS, 
      TABLEAU.GW_CLIENTS ACC
WHERE STATS.CLIENTID = ACC.ID(+)
```

Should be the same, I think

Comment: the same error. I read the code usage limits for fast materialized views, but I couldn't find the filter limitation and the use of the to_date function. 
Found a similar problem. But, I did not understand the solution:https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009AsHRP/trouble-getting-todate-to-work-in-a-materialized-view

Comment: PROBABLY CONFIRM THE CONCLUSION. USE FILTER ONLY IN QUICK UPDATE WITHOUT TABLE CONNECTIONS ...